# Where is my blunder in this angular momentum "identity"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, spherical-harmonics

I was searching for ways to reduce the following expression
$$
A = \sum_{m_3=-l_3}^{l_3}C_{l_1m_1,l_3m_3}^{l_2m_2} Y_{l_3m_3}(\hat u)
$$
where $\hat u$ is a unit vector, $Y_{lm}(\hat u)$ is a spherical harmonic, and
$$
C_{l_1m_1,l_3m_3}^{l_2m_2} = \int Y_{l_1m_1}^*(\hat v) Y_{l_2m_2}(\hat v) Y_{l_3m_3}^*(\hat v) \,d^2\hat v
$$
is a Gaunt integral. I thought I could move the spherical harmonic inside the integral and evaluate the sum using the addition property to obtain
$$
A = \frac{2l_3+1}{4\pi} \int Y_{l_1m_1}^*(\hat v) Y_{l_2m_2}(\hat v) P_{l_3}(\hat u\cdot\hat v) \,d^2\hat v
$$
To reduce the integral, I chose a spherical coordinate system in which the polar angle $\theta$ is measured with respect to $\hat u$, then
$$
A = \frac{2l_3+1}{4\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi} Y^*_{l_1m_1}(\theta,\phi) Y_{l_2m_2}(\theta,\phi) P_{l_3}(\cos\theta) \sin\theta \,d\theta\,d\phi
$$
Focusing on the azimuthal integral, and using the fact that the $\phi$ dependence of $Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)$ is just $e^{i m \phi}$,
$$\begin{align}
& \int_0^{2\pi} Y^*_{l_1m_1}(\theta,\phi) Y_{l_2m_2}(\theta,\phi)\, d\phi \\
&= Y^*_{l_1m_1}(\theta,0) Y_{l_2m_2}(\theta,0) \int_0^{2\pi}  e^{i(m_2-m_1)\phi}\, d\phi \\
&= Y^*_{l_1m_1}(\theta,0) Y_{l_2m_2}(\theta,0) \cdot 2\pi \delta_{m_1m_2} \\
\end{align}$$
With this, I concluded
$$
A = \frac{2l_3+1}{2} \delta_{m_1m_2} \int_0^\pi Y^*_{l_1m_1}(\theta,0) Y_{l_2m_1}(\theta,0) P_{l_3}(\cos\theta) \sin\theta \,d\theta
$$
and I was very pleased that the result was both independent of $m_2$ as well as independent of $\hat u$. If true, this would allow very nice computational savings in a code of mine.

However, when I numerically evaluate the original expression for $A$ to verify my result, neither of these properties come through. So I am led to think I made some blunder and that my result is too good to be true. Have I indeed made a mistake in my derivation?